# Can not find live

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I have a text to speech robot that I use for my livestreams on youtube.  The robot has been functioning fine for months.

It is giving me the error `"Can not find live"` despite having a livestream running.

My stream did particularly well yesterday, which may be related to why the API is behaving differently for me today?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my channel has been shadowbanned from appearing in search results for live videos.  The youtube-live-chat node api that I uses relies on a search to get the chat id.  Since I am shadowbanned from search results I must use the livebroadcasts list command instead.